# How to find number of holidays for monthly in python

Tags: python, pandas, calendar

I need to find number of holiday monthly wise for below code. Here i manually used value 2 for holiday of Jan month. How to manipulate no of holiday for current month using python script

code:

```
import datetime
import calendar

now = datetime.datetime.now ()
cal = calendar.Calendar ()
#working_days = len ( [x for x in cal.itermonthdays2 ( now.year, now.month ) if x[0] != 0 and x[1] < 5] ) - 2
working_days = len ( [x for x in cal.itermonthdays2 ( now.year, now.month ) if x[0] != 0 and x[1] < 5] )
available2 = working_days * 8
print(working_days)
```

Comment: please format your code.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get Number of Holidays per month in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59681579/get-number-of-holidays-per-month-in-python)

Comment: @AmirhosseinKiani - Here i don't have date column based on calendar library used to manipulate it. Above answer its not work for me

Comment: What's your source to detect a holiday? You could checkout the [`holidays`](https://pypi.org/project/holidays/) Python library